# Is the house being spied on?

Tags: spyware, countermeasure

A friend of mine noticed that her ex-husband seems to be spying on her. For instance he knows about vacations they are going to take without anyone else knowing and showing up there.

She already changed the passwords on her relevant accounts. The ex is not a tech-geek.

But sometimes he is sitting outside the house in the car. Could he be having installed something in the house and if so how to block it / get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec Ex Juergen, unfortunately, I don't think there is a security question here as a result I have flagged.

Comment: This is not a  "personal insecurity" SE. Anway, if suspicious, my advice is changing or factory reset the smartphone. If paranoid, check all the wire for any stranger device e.g. "baby bedroom speaker".

Comment: @mootmoot Actually I think personal security is on-topic, if it fits within the category of information security. This specific question, however, is likely not.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "Could he..." is "yes, many things, but there's insufficient data for us to help with them"...  That being said, **make sure the Wireless password got changed**.  If he's sitting in a car outside, he may be doing so to connect to the house network.

This sounds more like something your friend should be getting legal advice on... at the very least, the local police department will probably drop by in response to "My ex-husband is sitting in a car outside the house, there's no reason for him to be here, and I feel threatened."  This is not a technical issue.